# Enable gc logs for java applications in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, garbage-collection

How to enable GC logs for java applications running in kubernetes?

Comment: The same way you would without Kubernetes. Do you mean how to collect the logs and/or what's the best practice for it?

Comment: Thanks Gaël J !!